# Code that is a no-op in bash but stops with an error message in csh?

Tags: bash, csh

I am working with someone on a data analysis project and we frequently document the steps we perform by putting them into small shell scripts. The problem is that I use bash and the other person uses csh. The other person has a habit of using `source` to run these scripts instead of executing them directly (this habit probably dates back to times when spawning an extra shell was an extravagent waste of resources, so it's probably too entrenched to change) , and I want to have my scripts (which are, of course, bash scripts) simply stop with a message reminding the user to run them with bash instead of csh when this person sources them from within csh. At the same time, I would like them to continue to function as bash scripts.

So is there some code I can put at the beginning of my scripts that is a no-op in bash but will signal an error and cancel the execution of the rest of the file (but not kill the shell itself) when sourced from cshell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is harder than I thought due to csh's ancient variable substitution flavor. However, `$?BASH_VERSION` expands to 0 (not set) in csh and to `0BASH_VERSION` (or whatever the last commands' RV was) in bash. So,

```
test "$?BASH_VERSION" = 0 && exit 1
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Have you tested that? I don't know `csh`, but playing around just now, I found that `test -n "$BASH_VERSION" || ...` printed an error message but did *not* run `...`. But on the bright side, I also found that `exit` in a `source`d script did *not* kill the shell. (No clue why not.) So `exit` is a good start.

Comment: @ruakh: No, sorry. I assumed || would be sufficiently C-like to be in the csh.

Comment: @ruakh: `||` was OK, but the variable replacement killed me. Edited.

Comment: Looks like we have a winner! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Extra note: simply changing the `=` to `!=` reverses the test, so this can also be used to "protect" csh scripts from being executed by bash.

Comment: You can also print an error message with `test "$?BASH_VERSION" = 0 && echo "Error: this is a bash script" && exit 1`

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy, as you cannot assign variables the same way or run if statements the same way.

You can use csh's meagre string parsing skills against itself. The following executes cleanly in all shells, include KSH, BASH, ZSH, CSH and SH on all platforms that I tested it on (Linux, AIX, HP-UX, Solaris):

```
test '\\' = "\\" && echo "CSH detected"
```

The idea that is used is here is that backslashes are not special in double quoted strings on CSH, whereas all other shells do see them as different.

However, that is only half an answer as what do you want to do if you don't want to simply exit the script if the 'wrong' shell is detected? Well, you may want to have a Bournish `sh` part to your script and a `csh` part.

If you can keep the `csh` code limited to code that does not use single quotes, the following will work everywhere:

```
test '\\' = "\\" && goto csh
# Just skip the block containing the csh code. Again we use csh's meagre string parsing capabilities against it.
false || csh_code_block='
csh:
  ... csh code goes here ...
  exit 0
'
... sh code goes here ...
```

If you are not worried about HP-UX's `csh` (which seems a little better than others in parsing) you could replace the multi-line single quoted command with a 'HERE' document (`<<CSH_BLOCK ... CSH_BLOCK`). You can't just reverse the order either, as the 'goto' statement doesn't like all syntax that it skips over.

Comment: Thanks for the more general answer for how to embed (nearly) arbitrary code for both shells in a single script file.